# Seq2Seq Training helper module in tensorflow

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

In the latest tf 2.0 update tensorflow removed the contrib module from the framework. Thought they have compensated for most of the function from it in tf.compat.v1 but I couldn't find the substitute for the functions such as tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder , tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode , tf.contrib.seq2seq.GreedyEmbeddingHelper and tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper.
How to use these functions in my model?

Answer (score 0):

Check out TensorFlow-Addons:

https://github.com/tensorflow/addons,

https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/seq2seq?hl=en

the functions you are looking for are all there.

```
pip install tensorflow-addons
```

Then:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
```

Comment: But I can't install addons on windows